# getting data from wpf service in php

Tags: jquery, rest

Can any one give me an example to get the data from this url below which gives json data
This is working fine in when tested with firefox rest client 
i dont know how to consume this webservice from php or jquery

```
url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get in this way:

```
$.get('http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON', {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
  }, function(data) {
    alert(data.totalResultsCount);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rXPPc/) a jsfiddle with a working example